# Newline (carriage return) returned in blank fields

Tags: php, soap

SoapClient::__doRequest() is returning newline ("\n") characters inside empty fields.  The same Request executed in SoapUI does not.  See images below - The field "increment_id" contains a "\n" when the request is executed in PHP but not in SoapUI executable.  This is running on Windows.

phpStorm:

[image: Newline returned inside field - phpStorm]

SoapUI:

[image: Now newline inside field - SoapUI]

Is there any way to prevent the \n from being returned inside empty fields?

Comment: Use `<br>` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI is hiding the newlines in XML view.  Switching to "Raw" tab shows the newlines are there, so this is not a PHP issue.